# Tuples that contain a Boolean value can be compared. But the official documents says not

Tags: swift, boolean, tuples

The **Comparison Operators** section of **Basic Operators** part of the [Official documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) claims that "Tuples that contain a Boolean value can't be compared"

You can't say a true value is larger or less than a false value. But you can write the equal comparison on Boolean values

```
print((1, true) == (2, true)) // --> false
print((1, true) == (1, true)) // --> true
print((1, true) != (2, true)) // --> true
```

**Question** Is it an error from the document or I misunderstood the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comparison* actually means testing for equality, greater than and less than.

Equality is possible, the other not.

The protocol `Comparable` inherits from `Equatable`. An object must implement the operators `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` (practically only `<` because the other three can be inferred by the compiler) to conform to the `Comparable` protocol, additional to `==` of `Equatable`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is good to know that Comparison is an aggregate set invoices 3 compares together. But is that means if 3 of  them can be used for 2 variables then we can say those two variables are comparable?

Comment: `Comparable` requires the implementation of a bunch of operators. I updated the answer.

Comment: Actually you only need to implement two: `==` and `<`. The rest can be inferred by Swift

Comment: @CodeDifferent Right, thank you, I will add that, too.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood. "Compare" was used to mean `<` and `>`. In Swift, `false` is different from `true`, but not greater or less. Bools are not comparable by default.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from making them comparable:

```
extension Bool: Comparable {}

// Make false < true
public func < (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs == false && rhs == true
}

print( (1, false) < (2, false) ) // true
print( (true, 1) < (false, 1) )  // false
```

Comment: Nice to know that you can make them comparable by using the extension on the `Bool` protocol. Thanks